# Custom word weights for sentences when calling h2o transform and word2vec, instead of straight AVERAGE of words

Tags: word2vec, h2o

I am using H2O machine learning package to do natural language predictions, including the functions h2o.word2vec and h2o.transform.  I need sentence level aggregation, which is provided by the AVERAGE parameter value:

```
h2o.transform(word2vec, words, aggregate_method = c("NONE", "AVERAGE"))
```

However, in my case I strongly wish to avoid equal weighting of "the" and "platypus" for example.

Here's a scheme I concocted to achieve custom word-weightings.  If H2O's word2vec "AVERAGE" option uses all the words including duplicates that might appear, then I could effect a custom word weighting when calling h2o.transform by adding additional duplicates of certain words to my sentences, when I want to weight them more heavily than other words.

Can any H2O experts confirm that that the word2vec AVERAGE parameter is using all the words rather than just the unique words when computing AVERAGE of the words in sentence?

Alternatively, is there a better way?  I tried but I find myself unable to imagine any correct math to multiply the sentence average by some factor, after it was already computed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, h2o.transform will consider each occurrence of a word for the averaging, not just the unique words. Your trick will therefore work.

There is currently no direct way to provide user defined weights. You could probably do an ugly hack and weight directly the word embeddings but that won't be a straightforward solution I could recommend.

We can add this feature to H2O. I would love to hear what API would work for you (how would you like to provide the weights).